StateError (Bad state: field "message" does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)
I'm working on a chat application in Flutter using Firebase Firestore for storing messages. I'm encountering an error when trying to access the message field from a Firestore document. The error message is:Exception has occurred.
StateError (Bad state: field "message" does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)
Here is the relevant part of my chat_page.dart file:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenRoute = "ChatPage";

  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  late User? signedInUser;
  TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSignedInUser();
  }

  void getSignedInUser() {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      signedInUser = user;
    });
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage(String message, String receiverEmail) async {
    try {
      if (signedInUser != null) {
        final messageData = {
          'message': message,
          'senderId': signedInUser!.uid,
          'senderEmail': signedInUser!.email,
          'receiverEmail': receiverEmail,
          'timestamp': Timestamp.now(),
        };

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').add(messageData);
        _messageController.clear();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending message: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final name = args['name'];
    final imageLink = args['ImageLink'];
    final lastSeenTimestamp = args['lastSeen'];

    // Convert Firestore Timestamp to DateTime
    DateTime? lastSeenDateTime;
    if (lastSeenTimestamp != null && lastSeenTimestamp is Timestamp) {
      lastSeenDateTime = lastSeenTimestamp.toDate();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageLink),
        ),
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(name),
            Text(
              lastSeenDateTime != null ? formatLastSeen(lastSeenDateTime) : 'Last seen unknown',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                  );
                }

                final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: messages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final message = messages[index];
                    final messageText = message['message']; // Error occurs here
                    final senderId = message['senderId'];
                    final isMe = signedInUser?.uid == senderId;

                    return MessageReplay(
                      sendmessage: messageText,
                      isMe: isMe,
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _messageController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Type a message...',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final message = _messageController.text.trim();
                    final receiverEmail = 'receiver@example.com'; // Replace with the receiver's email address
                    if (message.isNotEmpty) {
                      sendMessage(message, receiverEmail);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String formatLastSeen(DateTime lastSeen) {
    Duration difference = DateTime.now().difference(lastSeen);
    if (difference.inDays > 0) {
      return 'Last seen ${difference.inDays} days ago';
    } else if (difference.inHours > 0) {
      return 'Last seen ${difference.inHours} hours ago';
    } else if (difference.inMinutes > 0) {
      return 'Last seen ${difference.inMinutes} minutes ago';
    } else {
      return 'Last seen just now';
    }
  }
}

class MessageReplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? sendmessage;
  final bool isMe;

  const MessageReplay({Key? key, this.sendmessage, required this.isMe})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Material(
            elevation: 5,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomLeft: isMe ? Radius.circular(30) : Radius.circular(0),
              bottomRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
            color: isMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Text(
                sendmessage ?? 'Message not found', // Handle null message
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


What I've Tried:
Ensured that the message field is being correctly added to Firestore when sending a message.
Verified that the Firestore collection and document paths are correct.
Question:
How can I resolve this StateError and ensure that the message field exists in the Firestore document before accessing it?
resolve this StateError and ensure that the message field exists in the Firestore document before accessing it?

Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.
